# App without main window - with many widgets showing one by one

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to have app without main window, but with many widgets showing one by one (dialogs won't work for me).

I have following code:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from start_window import Ui_Form
from second_window import Ui_Form as Ui_Form_Second

class StartForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button)

    def button(self):
        secondWindow = SecondForm()
        secondWindow.show()
        self.hide()


class SecondForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form_Second()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I press button app closes. How to pass execution of the app to the second widget?

Comment: Isn't `QWizard` or simple `QStackedWidget` is more suitable?

Comment: I am going to use timers and, at some point, two widget at the same time, so `QWizard` and `QStackedWidget` probably won't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't keep a reference to the widget you create in your `button` handler, so the widget is immediately destroyed.

Try something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from start_window import Ui_Form
from second_window import Ui_Form as Ui_Form_Second

class StartForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button)
        self.child_windows = []

    def button(self):
        secondWindow = SecondForm()
        secondWindow.show()
        self.child_windows.append(secondWindow)
        self.hide()


class SecondForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form_Second()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```